What is "team satisfaction" according to literature?
I am interested if there is a widely accepted definition of "team satisfaction" in the scientific literature.
My personal definition would be:

"Team satisfaction" refers to the degree to which members of a team
feel content, fulfilled, and positive about their participation and
experiences within the team.

But since I need to define it in a scientific context/paper, I was wondering if someone has already created a widely accepted definition.
